# Get list of projects in solution with MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution with a number of C++ projects (.vcxproj). There is one utility project with a custom build step. On this build step I would like to get a list of projects in solution and pass it to an external tool. Is there a way to have such a list? Something like `$(ProjectsInSolution)`?

See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51254ee1-abaf-496a-89f9-cf87fc2ae1e8/list-project-from-solution-sln-file?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 2):

> Get list of projects in solution with MSBuild

You could use [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)'s [GetSolutionProjects](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#GetSolutionProjects) for this question.

To accomplish this, create a new project in that solution, like `GetProjectsPath`. You should add [MSBuildTasks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuildTasks/) to your test project. After that, you will find following scripts in your project file(If not, add it manually):

```
<Import Project="..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets')" />
```

Then unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`, place below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="GetProjectsPath" AfterTargets="Build">
    <GetSolutionProjects Solution="..\GetProjectsPath.sln">
      <Output ItemName="ProjectFiles" TaskParameter="Output" />
    </GetSolutionProjects>
    <Message Text="Get Projects Path in the solution!" />
    <Message Text="Relative project paths:" />
    <Message Text="%(ProjectFiles.ProjectPath)" />
    <Message Text="Full paths to project files:" />
    <Message Text="%(ProjectFiles.FullPath)" />
  </Target>
```

When you build this project, you will get the all projects path in the solution:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely helps, thank you! I just wish it could be possible without additional .dll files to be added in my solution... So seems like it is impossible with bare MSBuild, correct?

Comment: @Mikhail, AFAIK, the answer is yes. If you do not want pull any dll file, you will need to overwrite the task `GetSolutionProjects`, but in that way, you will pull the .net framawork dll, like system.*.